# Is this the right approach?

Tags: java, software-design

Hi i have to write java code for the `"Game of Life"` game. The number of cells must be infinite.
Is the approach correct? I mean Design wise are they tightly coupled?

```
Class Universe
{
  Cell cells[];
}
 Class cell
{
  boolean live;
}
```

Comment: So what can i do about it?How to make the design loosely coupled?

Comment: **Interfaces**! Here's the first google result http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/30372

Comment: It's going to be hard to implement the infinite part.

Comment: Regarding "coupling" you don't have enough code and you have no class-class interaction to even comment on this. Keep going.

Comment: there is no answer to this. What little code you have above might be the perfect solution or the worst. You need to explain the context, what external requirements may impact the solution, etc. For example - why would you want to decouple the two classes? Flexibility is one answer but you may not need it. In software, principals and practices are there to guide you to the better solutions, not to be the solutions. So work out what your product needs to do, then figure out which patterns will help you to achieve that.

Comment: *"any solution for that ??"*  I read the solution as **Keep going.**  Were you reading another thread?  BTW - in case you are confused, SO is not a 'do my homework' service.

Comment: The solution is for you to write more code, code that involves class-to-class interaction. Then if you still have questions about its coupling, post this code. You shouldn't be asking this question until we first see your attempt, else you're cheating yourself by giving up too soon. Your brain cells have to sweat a little for you to learn. Trust me.

Comment: Another point is to also question what is meant by "Infinite". There is actually no such thing in IT. You will always be limited by either software or hardware limits. What strategies you employ (or if you need any) is going to be defined by what limits are in place.

Comment: @all i am not asking for the solution to my problem. I wanted the approach not the code.

Comment: We understand that, but still what is wrong with trying to solve it yourself first, what is preventing you from doing this?? And regardless your question is overly broad and vague. I have a feeling that your thoughts and questions will gain more form once you put in the effort and try to create code. So please do yourself a favor and do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an "infinite" amount of cells, then use some type of expandable list (ArrayList, LinkedList, etc).
However, you'll only be able to allocate as many cells as your computer memory will allow.
Don't really know what you mean by tightly/loosely coupled... explain?

Comment: Like i mean to say that if i change the properties of Cell of methods.Universe should not be effected by it.

Comment: You could also take the whole infinite thing a step further and store the data on your hard-drive like Minecraft does?
And only load the current region/visible region, idk just a suggestion.

Comment: properties as in variable values?

Comment: yup.put in one word my question is should the cell variable be in Universe or not.

Comment: If Cell relate directly to the Universe then yes, they should be in the Universe class. but if they relate to say, a Human object then they should be in the Human class and a list of Human objects should be in Universe.

Use: ArrayList<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<Cell>(); as your list.
Or: LinkedList<Cell> cells = new LinkedList<Cell>(); whichever fits your case better.